# ScrollView Layout does not fill the whole screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I got an `Activity` with two `Fragment`s (one list one normal). 
And the normal `Fragment` inflates a `Scrollview` containing a `LineaLayout` (vertical) and this layout contains `TextViews`.
The `ScrollView` and `layout_width` and `layout_height` are `match_parent`, so I think the whole screen should be used. But on the bottom there is still a "gap".
I hope you can help me.

ScrollView.xml

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/titlescreen_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="60dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_headline"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="60dp"
        android:paddingTop="60dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="@dimen/fontsize_slogan_titlescreen" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="30dp"
        android:paddingTop="30dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="@dimen/fontsize_slogan_titlescreen" />
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

the fragment inflating this layout.

```
package wak.iage.layout;

import wak.iage.R;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MenuContentFragment extends Fragment
{
LinearLayout.LayoutParams   relativeParams  = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
LinearLayout                topLayout       = null;
TextView                    body            = null;
TextView                    head            = null;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_content_main, container);
    return v;
}

public void changeText(String title, String content) {
    topLayout = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(
            R.id.LinearLayout1);
    head = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tv_headline);
    body = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tv_content);

    if (body == null) {
        topLayout.removeViews(1, topLayout.getChildCount() - 1);
        body = new TextView(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        body.setPadding(0, 30, 0, 20);
        body.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        body.setTextSize(22);
        body.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        topLayout.addView(body, relativeParams);
    }

    body.setText(content);
    head.setText(title);
}

public void addGlossary() {
    if (body != null) {
        topLayout.removeView(body);
    }

    int i = 0;

    for (int id : GLOSSARY) {
        TextView glossary = new TextView(getActivity()
                .getApplicationContext());
        glossary.setText(getString(id));
        glossary.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            glossary.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
            glossary.setTextSize(22);
            glossary.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 10);
        }
        topLayout.addView(glossary, relativeParams);
        i += 1;
    }
}

public static final int[]   GLOSSARY    = {
        R.string.GlossaryAndroidOSTitle, R.string.GlossaryAndroidOSContent,
        R.string.GlossaryAppTitle, R.string.GlossaryAppContent,
        R.string.GlossaryCloudTitle, R.string.GlossaryCloudContent,
        R.string.GlossaryDonwloadTitle, R.string.GlossaryDonwloadContent,
        R.string.GlossaryFacebookTitle, R.string.GlossaryFacebookContent,
        R.string.GlossaryGPSTitle, R.string.GlossaryGPSContent,
        R.string.GlossaryHomescreenTitle,
        R.string.GlossaryHomescreenContent, R.string.GlossaryPasswordTitle,
        R.string.GlossaryPasswordContent, R.string.GlossaryRouterTitle,
        R.string.GlossaryRouterContent, R.string.GlossarySDTitle,
        R.string.GlossaySDContent, R.string.GlossayStandbyTitle,
        R.string.GlossayStandbyContent, R.string.GlossaryTabletTitle,
        R.string.GlossaryTabletContent, R.string.GlossaryTouchscreenTitle,
        R.string.GlossaryTouchscreenContent, R.string.GlossayWidgetsTitle,
        R.string.GlossayWidgetsContent, R.string.GlossayWLANTitle,
        R.string.GlossayWLANContent };
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Edit: Even the proble is already fixed with: android:fillViewPort="true", I want to show you the problem.

But I don't have enough reputation to post a picture.
Sorry!

Comment: can you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 311, accepted):

If i'm not mistaken, the `ViewGroup`'s height (`LinearLayout`'s height in your case), that is the (only) child inside a `ScrollView`, is always interpreted as wrap_content, since that content can be larger than the `ScrollView`'s height (hence the scrollbars).

This also means that if the content is *smaller*, the `ScrollView`'s content (child) may not necessarily stretch to fill the screen.

In order to visually help you fix this, we need to see a screenshot of your problem.

Maybe setting `android:fillViewport="true"` on the `ScrollView` will fix your issue:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
```

Comment: Regarding "that is the (only) child inside a ScrollView, is always interpreted as wrap_content, since that content can be larger than the ScrollView's height (hence the scrollbars)": Couly you point me to the source code which does this?

Comment: In my case, the child `LinearLayout` had enough content to take more than the screen space but still, the Scrollview was not filling the screen and leaving like 10% of the screen at the bottom. fillViewPort fixed it. I had been messing with the code since yesterday. You are the savior man!

Comment: Yeas fillViewport="true" is this amazing thing that streches scrollview to entire screen height and enables to set content in center of screen in scroll view

Comment: `android:layout_height="match_parent"` should be `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Answer (score 11):

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" >
```

In your `ScrollView` add an attribute ie.

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

Comment: `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` should be `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Answer (score 2):

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_content_main, container);
```

should be

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_content_main, container, false);
```

Comment: Nope, this wasn't the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Replace ScrollView with NestedScrollView it will also solve the problem of nested scrolling.

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: This one worked for me , after trying all other suggestions here

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and could only fix it with a Helper Class. I found the original code online and this is my implementation of it.

#### Java class:

```
public class ImageViewHelper extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView {

    public ImageViewHelper(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ImageViewHelper(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ImageViewHelper(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        Drawable d = getDrawable();
        if (d != null) {
            int w = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            int h = w * d.getIntrinsicHeight() / d.getIntrinsicWidth();
            setMeasuredDimension(w, h);
        }
        else super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

#### XML:

```
<com.example.app.ImageViewHelper
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:src="@drawable/start"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
```