# Multiple GridViews with IMAGES, inside a ScrollView

Tags: android, android-studio, gridview, scrollview, android-image

[Selection Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3iTS.png)
[Selection Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nk2B7.png)

What i which to accomplish by using IMAGES inside a GridView is to allow the user to decide from ALL MY options which ones is he willing to do, the challenge throughout the whole process of creating this activity, has been trying to make it possible to fit everything in one screen with a ScrollView while maintaining the pictures.

In the images when the user has selected something it will be more opague (in the pictures is complete black).

I have been searching all over the place, and this is what has helped me so far:
- [ScrollView Layout does not fill the whole screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15094928/scrollview-layout-does-not-fill-the-whole-screen)
- [Gridview height gets cut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481844/gridview-height-gets-cut)

If any of you know a work around or other viable alternative, please dont hesitate to indulge me. I can also post my activity class, but i feel is redundant.

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/activity_woman_activities"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="tech.destinum.baewatch.WomanActivities">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/titleIndoorActivities"
    android:text="Indoor Activities"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="24sp"/>


<GridView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/gridviewWomanActivities"
    android:layout_below="@id/titleIndoorActivities"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:horizontalSpacing="8dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:minHeight="20dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/titleOutdoorActivities"
        android:text="Outdoor Activities"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gridviewWomanActivities"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"/>

    <GridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/gridviewWomanActivities2"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:horizontalSpacing="8dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:minHeight="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/titleOutdoorActivities"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <Button
        android:text="be spontaneous!"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/gridviewWomanActivities2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>



</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```